# No VS Code tem como ter um Color Theme para cada Linguagem?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

Minha dúvida é a seguinte. Eu gostaria de tem um tema de cores mais simples e com menos cores para trabalhar com CSS, já para o HTML eu gostaria de ter um Tema com cores mais acentuadas e marcadas.

Por exemplo ao abrir um arquivo `.HTML` eu quero usar o tema [Monokai](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=monokai.theme-monokai-pro-vscode), mas se eu abrir uma arquivo `.CSS` em outra aba eu quero o tema [Dracula](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gerane.Theme-Dracula)

Teria como configurar o VS Code para usar um *Color Theme* para cada extensão de arquivo ao mesmo tempo em abas diferentes?

---

***OBS:*** antes que me questionem perguntas sobre `ferramentas comuns entre programadores` são dentro do escopo do site ok https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Difícil essa... Estou revirando  o settings e os docs aqui  e nada...

Comment: @fernandosavio o máximo que consegui foi uma extensão... e um link de uma Issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20652

Answer (score 1):

Ainda não considero a opção perfeita. Mas consegui uma *extensão* do VS Code que faz isso!

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jsaulou.theme-by-language

Funciona assim, primeiro vc abre um arquivo com a extensão que vc quer, ou cria um arquivo novo e salva com a extensão que vc quer, tipo um `.html` ou `.js`

Então com esse arquivo aberto e a aba dele ativa na sua tela vc da um <kbd>ctrl+shit+p</kbd> e no prompt digita `Set theme for current file language` como na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora sempre que vc clicar em uma aba que tenha um arquivo com essa extensão aberto o seu tema vai mudar. O que eu não gostei é que ele troca o tema do VS Code como um todo, mas eu gostaria de usar as configs do tema novo só dentro do `Editor Workbench`

Veja como funciona: (tem um pequeno *delay* na troca de temas, mas acho que isso é questão de hardware...)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Não vou aceitar aminha própria resposta pq acho que no futuro terá um jeito melhor para tratar isso*